# Dataframe изменить столбец с датой

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Как превратить 'Timestamp' в столбец с обычной датой типа `1/14/2009`? [Данные тут](http://file.sampo.ru/w3862t/)

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
df
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [pd.read-csv(..., parse_dates=["Timestamp"])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv", parse_dates=["Timestamp"])
```

результат:

```
In [114]: df.head()
Out[114]:
   Timestamp  F
0 2012-01-03  1
1 2012-01-06  1
2 2012-01-09  1
3 2012-01-12  1
4 2012-01-15  1

In [115]: df.dtypes
Out[115]:
Timestamp    datetime64[ns]   #  <-- NOTE!!!
F                     int64
dtype: object
```

---

Если в данных присутствует хотя бы одна строка, где время не указывает на полночь (`00:00:00`), тогда Pandas будет показывать как дату так и время:

```
In [116]: df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv", parse_dates=["Timestamp"])

In [117]: df.head()
Out[117]:
            Timestamp  F
0 2012-01-03 21:59:00  1
1 2012-01-06 00:00:00  1
2 2012-01-09 00:00:00  1
3 2012-01-12 00:00:00  1
4 2012-01-15 00:00:00  1
```

Компоненту времени можно обрезать так:

```
In [118]: df["Timestamp"] = df["Timestamp"].dt.floor("D")

In [119]: df.head()
Out[119]:
   Timestamp  F
0 2012-01-03  1
1 2012-01-06  1
2 2012-01-09  1
3 2012-01-12  1
4 2012-01-15  1
```

Если вам нужно преобразовать дату к определенному формату - это делается так:

```
df["timestamp_str"] = df["Timestamp"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

результат:

```
In [121]: df.head()
Out[121]:
   Timestamp  F timestamp_str
0 2012-01-03  1    01/03/2012
1 2012-01-06  1    01/06/2012
2 2012-01-09  1    01/09/2012
3 2012-01-12  1    01/12/2012
4 2012-01-15  1    01/15/2012

In [122]: df.dtypes
Out[122]:
Timestamp        datetime64[ns]
F                         int64
timestamp_str            object  #  <-- NOTE!!!
dtype: object
```

**NOTE:** после такого преобразования вы получите строки вместо дат и как следствие вы не сможете воспользоваться ни одной функцией для работы с датами/временем, включая арифметику дат. Обычно даты преобразовывают в определенный формат только перед тем как сохранить их в текстовом виде или для вывода на экран/график.

Comment: почему то изменений не призошло, Timestamp стал datetime64[ns], но все также так цифры даты и времени в одном столбце

Comment: @gur521, у вас в данных есть строки в которых время не равно "0:00"? Вы хотите обрезать компоненту времени?

Comment: @gur521, если речь об определенном формате, то этот столбец будет иметь тип данных `object` (строка) - соответственно вы не будете иметь возможность производить никаких действий с датами. Для чего и в какой момент вам нужен определенный формат дат?